# Is there any configuration to avoid skipped after falied one test cases in nightwatch?

Tags: testing, automation, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I have a test automation framework for regression test cases using nightwatch.
Now the problem with this framework is: all cases skiped one case is failed.

**Is there any configuration to avoid skipped after falied one test cases in nightwatch?**

Answer (score 1):

`skip_testcases_on_fail: false` and if that doesn't work use `.verify` instead of `.assert`

I couldn't find official documentation for `skip_testcases_on_fail`, just some references on nightwatch repository issues.

**Update:**

`skip_testcases_on_fail` is documented here: http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#test-settings
and according to documentation is set to `true` by default, thus setting it to `false` should work for your case